# Installing with pip breaks on python setup.py egg_info

Tags: python, setuptools, pip

I'm trying to install my own program via Pip and the PyPI with the usual command `pip install tvrenamr` however I'm getting the error below:

```
Downloading/unpacking tvrenamr
  Running setup.py egg_info for package tvrenamr
    Usage: tvr [options] <file/folder>

    -c: error: no such option: --egg-base
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Usage: tvr [options] <file/folder>



-c: error: no such option: --egg-base

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 2
Storing complete log in /Users/george/.pip/pip.log
```

It's been a while since I checked but I used to be able to pip install my code with the previous versions I put on the PyPI, however I updated to the latest Pip - not sure if would cause things to break or not!

So when pip is running `python setup.py egg_info` it seems that TvRenamr is being called, or at least my option parser class has been imported.

My `setup.py`:

```
from os.path import dirname, join
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

from tvrenamr import get_version

def fread(fname):
    return open(join(dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

setup(
    name = 'tvrenamr',
    version = get_version(),
    description = 'Rename tv show files using online databases',
    long_description = fread('README.markdown'),
    author = 'George Hickman',
    author_email = 'george@ghickman.co.uk',
    url = 'http://github.com/ghickman/tvrenamr',
    license = 'MIT',
    packages = find_packages(exclude=['tests']),
    entry_points = {'console_scripts': ['tvr = tvrenamr.tvrenamr:run',],},
    classifiers = [
        'Environment :: Console',
        'Intended Audience :: End Users/Desktop',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Operating System :: MacOS',
        'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows',
        'Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
        'Topic :: Multimedia',
        'Topic :: Utilities',
        'Natural Language :: English'],
    install_requires = ('lxml', 'pyyaml',)
)
```

`tvrenamr/__init__.py`:

```
__version__ = (3, 0, 0)

def get_version():
    return '.'.join(map(str, __version__))
```

My only thoughts on how it's getting tvrenamr's options now are that either `find_packages` or the `entry_points` option are in some way importing `tvrenamr.py` and thus `options.py`??

All versions of TvRenamr were uploaded to the PyPI with `python setup.py sdist upload`.

I really am stumped with this problem - any help much appreciated!

EDIT: I can run `python setup.py egg_info` with no errors.

Comment: Try running `python setup.py egg_info` directly and see if it reproduces the error.  If it does, then this isn't related to pip so update the question.

Comment: Tried here in a fresh virtualenv, using pip 1.0.1 and it installed with no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this was a case of setup tools masking an error in the setup.py that was being caused by a bad version string in `tvrenamr/__init__.py`.

I picked up on the error after installing manually with `python setup.py install` into a clean virtualenv so something in my environment must have been affecting things before too.